# How did Yoda react to Dooku's death?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, yoda, darth-tyranus

Inspired by this video,

The fact that Dooku is Yoda's former apprentice it would make sense to the audience on how Yoda reacted on it. The Jedi always strive for redemption with love. It makes me wonder, why didn't Yoda react any on it? With Obi-Wan/Vader they have a tense relationship that a Master doesn't want his former apprentice to be dead. Now in both the movie and the novel it didn't offer any evidence on how Yoda reacted to it. In fact, the video above by *Stupendous Wave* is just his theory. **Is there any evidence from novels, comics, etc. that would suggest how Yoda reacted to the death of his former apprentice?**

Comment: Dooku or Dooku not. There is no die.

Comment: Probably meditated a bit, and then after that meditated a bit more.

Comment: Yoda was a powerful Jedi, meaning he had no attachment with anyone or anything (other than his weired speech, ofcourse)..

Answer (score 7):

We know from the films that Yoda (and Obi-Wan's) perspective is that a Jedi that has turned to the dark side of the Force is **already effectively dead.** Returning them to the light is, *as far as they're aware*, totally impossible. That being the case, he would have already felt the loss of his ertwhile Padawan long before he actually died. With a bit of an edit, we can re-use Obi-Wan's quote to give some voice to this.

> **<s>Obi-Wan</s> Yoda**: *He ceased to be <s>Anakin Skywalker</s> Count Dooku and became <s>Darth Vader</s> Darth Tyranus. When that happened, the good man who was <s>your father</s> my pupil was destroyed. So what I told you was true, from a certain point of view.*

I think we can be reasonably sure that someone as emotionally balanced as Yoda would have accepted the news with calmness, then meditated on his feelings of loss at a more appropriate time later. Beyond that, he's usually pretty chill about people dying, viewing it as a natural part of life.

---

Moving down the canon scale, we have this exchange from [***Yoda: Dark Rendezvous***](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda:_Dark_Rendezvous). Yoda and Dooku fight and Yoda comes close to killing Dooku.

> *“Yes,” Dooku whispered. “Feel me. Feel the treason. All those years of
>   teaching me, raising me. Trusting me. And here am I, the favored son,
>   butchering your precious Jedi, one by one. Hate me Yoda. You know you
>   want to.“*
>
> ...
>
> Dooku brought his blade down toward the diminutive Jedi Master and
>   Yoda parried, locking his blade against Dooku’s. Yoda breathed,
>   calming himself.
>
> *“And yet, even here on Vjun, where the dark side whispers and whispers
>   to me… **love you enough to destroy you I do.”***

Comment: Although Luke clearly demonstrated that returning a fellow force-sensitive to the light was possible.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - Indeed, hence "*as far as they're aware*" since this appears to be the only time it's worked and something that Yoda and Obi-Wan felt was a waste of Luke's energies in pursuing.

Comment: I often wonder, thus, if Anakin TRULY has turned, OR if he was partially turned, but addicted more than passionate about the dark side. He was torn inside about what he had done to the Jedi/Padme but couldn’t resist the dark side either. Luke simply helped him “break out” of that addiction and see what was truly important.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - I would strongly suggest you read the novelisation of Revenge of the Sith. It goes into considerable detail about his (early) ambivalence but how he eventually overcomes the light side in his personality.

Comment: If Yoda views Dooku and Tyranus aren't the same, Why didn't Yoda redeem Dooku?

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar - Because he didn't think it was possible.

Comment: So it means Luke was the bettter Jedi

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar - He was open to a possibility that Yoda and Obi-Wan had rejected. That doesn't make him a better Jedi, per se

Comment: I mean the Jedi always strive for Redemption.

Answer (score 1):

### Despite all of his training, Yoda still felt something for Dooku

Philosophy of old Jedi Order (before Order 66) was non-attachment, letting go of the things, those who turn to the Dark Side remain there etc ... Yoda himself, as Grand Master of the Order, held to those beliefs and publicly preached them many times to other Jedi (including Anakin, and much latter to his son Luke).

Yet, there are hints that Yoda never truly accepted Dooku's betrayal, especially not in such detached and definitive manner. In final episodes of *Clone Wars* (well, final before Disney start meddling :) ) Yoda twice meets Dooku during his Force visions. In episode [Destiny](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Destiny_(episode)) Yoda has a vision of Jedi Temple in an alternate timeline without Clone War. Among the other Jedi there is Dooku, who acts friendly like nothing has happened between him and Yoda. Yoda almost accepts this vision, before finding strength to recognize it as an illusion. Then in [Destiny](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Destiny_(episode)), Yoda has a vision of him and Anakin fighting vs Dooku and Sidious. Anakin beats Dooku and proceeds to behead him (in the same manner he did later in real life). Yoda tries to stop him, in vain.

Both of these visions show that Yoda still had some attachments to Dooku, despite all of Jedi orthodoxy. Also, there was a premonition on his part that as long as Dooku lives, Sith still held something back. There was still certain sense of honor within Dooku, and only with his death things would finally deteriorate to a breaking point. We don't have explicit description of Yoda's reaction to Dooku's death, but after that he was very troubled by looming threat that was gathering over Jedi Order. Subconsciously, Yoda probably wanted to have Dooku back (first Force vision, playing on his wishes, shows that), only he could not publicly admit that. When Dooku died, all of Yoda's hopes died with him, including the hope that war could be resolved peacefully.